# Is there a difference between using between vs '> & <' when querying a hive table partitioned on date string?

Tags: performance, hive, hiveql

I have a use of selecting data from a large hive table partitioned on date (format : `yyyyMMdd`), the hive query is required to fetch few fields from 6 months of data (total 180 date partitions. Currently the query looks like :

```
SELECT field_1, field_2 
FROM table 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '20181125' and '20190525'
```

Wanted to know if changing the query to use `>= & <=` makes any difference in terms of performance.

```
SELECT field_1, field_2 
FROM table 
WHERE `date`>='20181125' AND `date`<='20190525'
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any significant changes in the performance while using < > instead of **Between** keyword .

How ever using **IN** keyword and listing down all the dates between the range will have a slight advantage over the other two scenarios .

```
SELECT field_1, field_2 FROM table WHERE dates in ('20181125','20181126',...,'20190524','20190525');
```

Answer (score 0):

`>=, <=` and `BETWEEN` should generate the same execution plans, though it may be different in your Hive version.

Use [EXPLAIN](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain), it shows the query execution plan. Only plan can help to answer this question for sure. Check `EXPLAIN DEPENDENCY`, it prints `input_partitions` to be scanned and you will see if partition pruning works or not in each case.

If plans are the same for `>=, <=`, `BETWEEN` and `IN` then it works the same and the performance should be the same.